# How to save currently playing radio station?

Tags: banshee, internet-radio

If I go a a URL like http://somafm.com/play/groovesalad130 in Firefox, the browser prompts me to load a *.pls file in Banshee.  When loaded, this successfully plays the radio station in Banshee.  How can I save this radio station permanently, so that I don't have to go the web page to trigger it?

I know about the "Add a new Internet Radio station" button and window, but I would like to be able to "save" or "bookmark" the currently playing station, instead of having to dig out the links myself.

Answer (score 1):

**1** - In Banshee click on **Add A New Internet Station Or Playlist**

**2** - Then in the **Stream URL** field copy and paste: http://www.somafm.com/groovesalad.pls

**3** - In the **Station Name** enter the station name

**4** - In the **Station Genre** drop-down menu choose from the list

For some unknown reason you need to fill the Station Genre in before it will allow you to save the station.

**5** - Click **Save**

*I have just tested this and it works, even after I have restarted Banshee the radio station I added was there and was working perfectly.*

Comment: That's not the currently playing radio station, that's a new radio station, for which you already know the URL.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option for saving the currently played radio station at the moment using Banshee.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at the moment there's no option in Banshee to save currently playing radio station.

**What you can do is:**

1. Instead of opening with Banshee, **Save the *.pls file** (or *.m3u) on your drive
2. Click on the file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. It will copy location information of the file.
3. Go back to Banshee, select 'Radio' from the context pane on the left site and then click **'Add a new Internet Radio station or playlist'** (Green plus button located next to search box)
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste into 'Stream URL' box the location of your *.pls or *.m3u file
5. Fill the rest of the boxes (gerne, name and url are necessary)  and then **Save** the station